# Multiple POST backends in KrakenD API Gateway

Tags: api-gateway, krakend

Can I have a KrakenD API Gateway POST endpoint which connects to multiple POST backends?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Multiple backends are just allowed for "safe" methods. Check this comment for more details: https://github.com/luraproject/lura/issues/194#issuecomment-460470842

But you can create a custom client plugin and manage the transaction by yourself

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).